# How do I change the background color of a selected react-bootstrap ToggleButton?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using react-bootstrap and am trying to change the background color of a *selected* `<ToggleButton>` to blue.

e.g.:

```
<ButtonToolbar>
  <ToggleButtonGroup
    type="radio"
    name="options"
    value={...}
    onChange={...}>
    <ToggleButton ... />
    <ToggleButton ... />
    <ToggleButton ... />
  </ToggleButtonGroup>
</ButtonToolbar>
```

So instead of the dark grey you see below for M/W/F I'd like blue.  I've tried a billion CSS tricks and just can't get it to take.  Thanks!

[image: togglebuttonexample]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this is CSS by adding the following class and style rule.

!important is needed to override the react-bootstrap library's style.

```
.Btn-Blue-BG.active {
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

and

```
<ToggleButton className="Btn-Blue-BG" ...>
```

See demonstration below:

https://codesandbox.io/s/6nwkwnn29z

Comment: That did it - thank you!  -- Any idea on how to get the nice gradient effect they've got?

Comment: Got it: `background-image: linear-gradient(#295c87, #3679b2) !important;`

Comment: Follow-up question - how would I style the active/hover state of said button?

Comment: You can add a new rule, `.Btn-Blue-BG.active:hover {...}` for styling the hover over selected buttons, and `.Btn-Blue-BG:hover {...}` for styling the hover of non-selected and selected buttons

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding `bsStyle="primary"` ?

```
<ButtonToolbar>
    <ToggleButtonGroup
        type="radio"
        name="options"
        value={...}
        onChange={...}>
        <ToggleButton ... />
        <ToggleButton bsStyle="primary" />
        <ToggleButton ... />
        <ToggleButton bsStyle="primary" />
        <ToggleButton ... />
        <ToggleButton bsStyle="primary" />
        <ToggleButton ... />
      </ToggleButtonGroup>
    </ButtonToolbar>
```

Comment: That's close!  However I'm looking to have the "primary" style for only the `checked` state.

Comment: How do you know that the `primary` style would be set to blue?